# Error:Failed to find: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3

Tags: android, gradle, gson

I'm trying to add Gson library into my gradle, but it isn't finding the library. I've tried almost all the versions and nothing works.

My dependencies is following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    // Volley
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar'

    // Gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

}
```

Any solution, please?

Comment: did You clean the Project? because I had a similar issue.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LKUW2.png

Comment: I've already cleaned

Comment: Yes like EugenPechanec said Offline work should be unchecked.

Comment: yes, but is not offline checked

Comment: Then open Project Structure and select Dependency press + sign select library dependency Search For gson

Answer (score 0):

Try this and sync the project and be sure internet is connected.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```